# How can I find the underlying column and table name for an Oracle view?

Tags: oracle, view, metadata

This sounds like it should be simple to do but not so! There is no Oracle (meta-data) view that I can find that gives the underlying column and table name for an Oracle view column. The only way I have found of doing it is to parse the view source SQL (which is far from and exact science).

Just to explain what I want, consider the following example view which I created in SCOTT schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_DEP
(
   EMPLOYEE_NAME,
   DEPARTMENT_NAME
)
AS
SELECT 
   ENAME,
   DNAME 
FROM
   emp a,
   dept b
WHERE
   a.deptno= b.deptno
/
```

Now given the view and column name EMP_DEP.DEPARTMENT_NAME, I would like to get the underlying table and column name used by the view which is DEPT.DNAME. Does anyone know of a way to get this information that does not involve parsing the view's SQL?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way, because the definition of each view column is an **expression**, not (in general) merely a table column.  For example, your view's SQL could be:

```
SELECT 
   UPPER(ENAME) || 'xxx',
   myfunction(DNAME)
FROM
   emp a,
   dept b
WHERE
   a.deptno= b.deptno
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT ename || 'xxx', dname
FROM (
  SELECT 
     UPPER(ENAME) AS ename,
     myfunction(DNAME) AS dname
  FROM
     emp a,
     dept b
  WHERE
     a.deptno= b.deptno
)
```

What would you expect to see for the "underlying columns" in this example?

Comment: True (and I was aware of this). In this case it should just return nothing because its an expression.

Comment: It would be nice if some dependencies query would return emp.ename and dept.dname, making it easier to identify where changes to the underlying table/column would affect a view/procedure/etc.... but TOAD provides a lot of that information on the "used by" tab, so at least it's easy to check manually.

Answer (score 2):

Tables used to created the view can be selected using the query:

```
select 
  name , 
  type , 
  referenced_name , 
  referenced_type
from 
  user_dependencies 
where 
  name = 'VIEW_NAME' and 
  type = 'VIEW' and  
  referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

If view columns have the same column name of table column, then please try the below query:

```
select 
  distinct table_name, column_name 
from 
  all_tab_columns 
where table_name in (select
                        referenced_name
                      from 
                        user_dependencies 
                      where 
                        name = 'VIEW_NAME' and 
                        type = 'VIEW' and  
                        referenced_type = 'TABLE') 
 and column_name in (select 
                        column_name 
                     from 
                        all_tab_columns 
                     where 
                        table_name = 'VIEW_NAME');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the requester is looking for any instance of his table, and not with respect to a specific view, I would recommend:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
 WHERE TYPE = 'VIEW'
   AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND REFERENCED_NAME = '<TABLE_NAME>'
```

Comment: 2.5 years later this was again helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The sql that defined the view can be found in all_views

```
set long 9999 
select TEXT from all_views where VIEW_NAME='MYVIEW';
```

This is the only way to get at the underlying tables and columns.

Answer (score 1):

In 11g Oracle introduced [finer grained dependency tracking](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO07519).  So the database knows which table columns a view or package body depends on.  However, they don't seem to have exposed this data in a view.  But there may be x$ tables with the info.

Answer (score 1):

The [linked procedures](http://api.ning.com/files/4aZU773WSvvWf0bQHTO-rzrBua5qqIYcPtQYV*Irgppvi7i-hXG4SMOdCAztlc4jKG-1IXnaaou2avBIDcDJ1BNORA5q0xd5/show_dependencies.sql) may be of some help for identifying dependencies

The DBA_DEPENDENCIES View will give you a list of the tables that a View is based on:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES
 WHERE OWNER = <Schema>
   AND NAME = <View_Name>
   AND TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

Comment: Super old post but this saved me hours of digging through views for permissions! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

This works well if you want a views table and column dependencies:

```
WITH view_dependencies (view_name, table_name) AS (
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT d.name AS view_name, d.referenced_name AS table_name
    FROM all_dependencies d
    WHERE d.referenced_type IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW')
    START WITH d.name = UPPER('jtf_rs_resource_extns_vl') AND d.type = 'VIEW'
    CONNECT BY PRIOR d.referenced_name = d.name AND PRIOR d.referenced_type = d.type
)
SELECT deps.view_name, deps.table_name, tbl.table_id, cols.column_id, 
       cols.column_name  
FROM view_dependencies deps
    LEFT JOIN FND_TABLES tbl ON tbl.table_name = deps.table_name
    LEFT JOIN FND_COLUMNS cols ON tbl.table_id = cols.table_id
ORDER BY deps.view_name,  deps.table_name, cols.column_sequence;
```

**Outputs**

```
VIEW_NAME                   TABLE_NAME            TABLE_ID COLUMN_ID COLUMN_NAME
=======================================================================================
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563724  RESOURCE_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563712  CREATED_BY
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563713  CREATION_DATE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563718  LAST_UPDATED_BY
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563719  LAST_UPDATE_DATE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563720  LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563704  CATEGORY
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563725  RESOURCE_NUMBER
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563729  SOURCE_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563686  ADDRESS_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563709  CONTACT_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563721  MANAGING_EMPLOYEE_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563730  START_DATE_ACTIVE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563714  END_DATE_ACTIVE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563732  TIME_ZONE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563711  COST_PER_HR
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563723  PRIMARY_LANGUAGE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563726  SECONDARY_LANGUAGE
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563717  IES_AGENT_LOGIN
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563728  SERVER_GROUP_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563687  ASSIGNED_TO_GROUP_ID
JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS_VL    JTF_RS_RESOURCE_EXTNS   80056   563710  COST_CENTER
```