# Find the ColumnName and the table from which the column is coming in a View

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a View created and i want to find all the columns that are present in the view along with the source table in which the column is present . Eg :

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT  
        firstName,
        middleName,
        you.lastName surName
FROM 
        myTable me
        LEFT OUTER JOIN yourTable you
        ON me.code = you.code
```

GO

So here i would like data as below

```
 ----------------
|SourceTable|Column |
----------------
|me         |firstName|
|me         |middleName|
|you        |lastName|
```

Can anyone Help me with this .
P.S : I need it for *Oracle*

Comment: So you mean the output of the view should be source table name and the column names as rows?

Comment: Yes as shown in the question

Comment: No i tried that , it is not working !!!

Comment: If you tried something in the duplicate please say _exactly_ what and reference it in your question @adityaswami89. Reference it in your question _before_ you post it. There's no point anyone helping you if you just tell them that you've tried it when you haven't told them that. Equally, "it's not working" means nothing. If something isn't working you need to explain exactly why you think so and include error messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the column name exists only in one table among the tables used in the view then we could find it with below query.

```
select table_name, column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name in ("tables used") 
 and column_name in (select column_name 
                     from all_tab_columns 
                     where table_name = 'view_name');
```

Comment: Yes but there may be a case where 1 column may exist in multiple places . How to cater to this problem ?

Comment: And this is not giving me the required output as well :( leavingthe multiple places problem

Comment: Then you have read the text column of user_views and fetch the details with help of pl/sql block.

Comment: @adityaswami89 well the issue that you are saying will always be there , because the table you are using in view may have same columns.

Answer (score 0):

Tables used to created the view can be selected using the query:

```
select 
  name , 
  type , 
  referenced_name , 
  referenced_type
from 
  user_dependencies 
where 
  name = 'VIEW_NAME' and 
  type = 'VIEW' and  
  referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

If view columns have the same column name of table column, then please try the below query:

```
select 
  distinct table_name, column_name 
from 
  all_tab_columns 
where table_name in (select
                        referenced_name
                      from 
                        user_dependencies 
                      where 
                        name = 'VIEW_NAME' and 
                        type = 'VIEW' and  
                        referenced_type = 'TABLE') 
 and column_name in (select 
                        column_name 
                     from 
                        all_tab_columns 
                     where 
                        table_name = 'VIEW_NAME');
```

Comment: From this i dont get the Tables from where the columns are coming from !!!!

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified Tables and not columns in the description and I guess this post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101078/how-can-i-find-the-underlying-column-and-table-name-for-an-oracle-view/18909678#18909678